# Grep com múltiplos parâmetros

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Preciso selecionar as linhas de um arquivo que contém os caracteres `|` ou `\`

```
diff -y ontem.csv hoje.csv | grep -e "|" -e "\"
```

Como dizer pro grep me retornar as linhas que contém ou um pipe `|` ou uma barra `\` ??

Comment: O que retorna neste comando que você postou ?

Comment: Retorna as linhas do diff, como se o grep não tivesse sido feito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar os delimitadores `[]`, que [pegam todos os caracteres que estiverem dentro deles](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (a `\` deve ser escapada, então fica `\\`):

```
grep -e "[\\|]"
```

Veja exemplos desta regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/hTU2M7/1).

---

Conforme informado nos comentários, o `grep` também funciona sem a opção `-e` e sem precisar escapar a barra:

```
grep "[\|]"
```

Comment: O parametro `-e` é dispensável e não é preciso escapar a barra.

Comment: @Lacobus Tem razão. É que primeiro eu testei no regex101.com e lá só funciona se escapar a barra, mas no grep não precisa mesmo. Quanto ao parâmetro `-e`, é um velho hábito que tenho de usar sempre, mesmo quando não precisa...

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a expressão regular `[\|]`, veja só:

**grep:**

```
$ diff -y ontem.csv hoje.csv | grep '[\|]'
```

**egrep:**

```
$ diff -y ontem.csv hoje.csv | egrep '[\|]'
```

**awk:**

```
$ diff -y ontem.csv hoje.csv | awk '/[\\|]/{print}'
```

**perl:**

```
$ diff -y ontem.csv hoje.csv | perl -nle 'print if m{[\\|]}'
```

**sed:**

```
$ diff -y novas.csv entrada.txt | sed -n '/[\|]/p'
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue:

```
diff -y ontem.csv hoje.csv | grep "[|\]"
```

Veja mais em --> https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

Vc também pode usar `egrep` --> https://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep

Comment: Não é necessário escapar a barra e nem o pipe.

Comment: @Lacobus valew pela correção! Abs.